# can somebody explain the meaning of following code

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-handling

```
function handleEnter(event) {
      if (event.key==="Enter") {
          const form = document.getElementById('form')
          const index = [...form].indexOf(event.target);
          form.elements[index + 1].focus();
        }
    }
```

This code is use for focusing on next input field after pressing Enter somebody explain me this code line by line? it will be big help

Comment: stackoverflow is not really a learning platform. You can learn more about events in javascript on for example [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) or [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/build-interactive-websites/modules/dom-javascript-events)

Comment: The key line of code is this one: `form.elements[index + 1].focus();` The other lines of code  are just setup instructions for this line.  Over time, you will gain enough experience in the JavaScript language and the Document Object Model to be able to read lines of code like this easily.

Answer (score 2):

Line 1:

```
const form = document.getElementById('form')
```

Get the DOM element from html

Line 2:

```
const index = [...form].indexOf(event.target);
```

Find in the form elements the index of the current element. I think this line is not correct, I suppose that you want to get child elements from the form element, if so, it should be something like:

```
const index = form.children.indexOf(event.target);
```

Line 3:

```
form.elements[index + 1].focus();
```

The next element should be the current index plus 1, so just run `focus` on next element, but as I said, I think that your `line 2` is not correct so this line should be something like:

```
form.children[index + 1].focus();
```

Comment: `[...form].indexOf(event.target);` is fine. It spreads the **elements** collection (not the children collecton) of the form, puts them in an array and find the index of the target control within that array.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand.
2nd line : This funct will perform only when press Enter key
3rd line : get information from the form input ("form" ID)
4th line : get the index of the form input
5th line : move the focus point to the next element (which is index+1)

Comment: There's a lot more to explaining a simple code snippet than this, if you start from a position of no knowledge.  I would expect a good answer to a question like this to be several paragraphs long.

Comment: ok sorry about that. Just trying to understand it as simple as possible

Answer (score 0):

Bro, understanding this code is quite easy you just need to break it down.
Let's start with it :-

- First it is JavaScript function in which html event is passed as argument.
- Second checks whether the event that is triggered is **enter key event**
- If yes, then the next statement will be executed that will select element with **form** as id.
- Now from the all the input fields of form current input field will be selected.
- At last, the index of element that is focus is increment that will shift the focus to next input field in the form.